# HTML email does not show up in Mailcatcher, but text does

Tags: django, email, mailcatcher

Where can I look for logs that might help me find the cause of this? I have a Django app configured to deliver non-production environments email to a server running Mailcatcher. When I send text only email, it shows up in Mailcatcher, when I add the alternative HTML content, they do not.

I'm using `EmailMultiAlternatives` and to test this I am commenting out my line with `attach_alternative()` to send the text only, it is working fine. No errors from runserver, and `email.send()` is returning 1.

Fails:

```
@staticmethod
def send_payment_confirmation(client, free_trial_days, recur_id):
    context = {
        'recur_id': recur_id,
        'client': client,
        'free_trial_days': free_trial_days
    }
    html_body = render_to_string('email/html/payment_confirmation.html', context)
    text_body = render_to_string('email/text/payment_confirmation.txt', context)

    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=u"Thank You For Your Payment,{}".format(client.name),
                                   body=text_body, to=[client.get_contact_email()], bcc=['support@example.com'])
    email.attach_alternative(html_body, "text/html")
    email.send()
```

Works:

```
@staticmethod
def send_payment_confirmation(client, free_trial_days, recur_id):
    context = {
        'recur_id': recur_id,
        'client': client,
        'free_trial_days': free_trial_days
    }
    html_body = render_to_string('email/html/payment_confirmation.html', context)
    text_body = render_to_string('email/text/payment_confirmation.txt', context)

    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=u"Thank You For Your Payment,{}".format(client.name),
                                   body=text_body, to=[client.get_contact_email()], bcc=['support@example.com'])
    # email.attach_alternative(html_body, "text/html")
    email.send()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are spelling the names correctly? In your question they are all wrong (`EmailMultiAlternitives` and `attach_alternitive()`)

Comment: Sorry, typos. They are correctly spelled in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, it's a known bug with MailCatcher. Versions after `0.5.12` crash when they are sent `utf8` html email. Current version is `0.6.4` - 2/4/16 (and still has the issue).

Downgrading to `0.5.12` resolves the problem.

https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/201